# Understanding Indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Here is my understanding of indexes, can someone confirm if I've missed something or something is inaccurate?

Clustered

- You can only have 1 per table.
- Stores data based on the order of the column(s) that you are trying to create it on.
- A primary key is a clustered index by default.
- A clustered index is a rowstore index by default.

Non-clustered

- You can have up to 999 per table.
- Data is not sorted in any sort of way, it just provides pointers to
  access your data faster based on the columns involved on the index.
- A primary key can be non-clustered as well.
- A non-clustered index is a rowstore index by default.

Columnstore

- You can only have 1 per table.
- Each column is stored separately from the rest of the columns. If you have 5 columns, that is 5 pages.
- Better for using with fact tables
- Uses less space than rowstore.
- Segments are stored in rowgroups.
- Better if you are retrieving a small number of columns from the
  table.

Rowstore

- Better for using with OLTP Databases or Dimensions.
- Uses more space than columnstore.
- Better if you are retrieving a large number of columns from the
  table.
- Data is stored 1 row at a time.

Clustered Columnstore Indexes

- If you have a clustered columnstore index, you cannot have any other
  index on the table, this includes non-clustered. If non-clustered
  already exists, you will have to drop them first.
- If you have a clustered columnstore index, you cannot have a primary key on the same table.

Basically, I'm just trying to understand the difference between the 4, which case is better suited for what, which case is not suited for what, etc.

The above is what I have gathered based on my research.

Is there anything important I am missing? Is something incorrect?

Comment: As of SQL 2016 you can have non-clustered indexes and a Clustered Columnstore Index.

Comment: Two points for the *non-clustered* index: **(1)** the data in the index (the index columns) **IS** sorted at the leaf level - so if you do a leaf-level scan of a NCI, you get these columns in a sorted fashion (but only these columns in the index - not the whole set of data), and **(2)** each NCI - at the leaf-level - contains not only those columns you've defined to be part of the index (plus any *included* columns), it also includes the **clustering key columns** to do key lookups

Comment: You should also be clear that the "sorting" of both NCIs and CIs is logical not necessarily physical. If you read the pages at leaf level by following the linked list and read the rows on the page in slot array order then you will read in sorted order but physically the pages may not be sorted.